# Should I back-calculate soft labels (probabilities) of my training set when I use probabilistic classifiers?

Tags: classification

I have 2 datasets (D1, D2) to train 2 models (M1, M2).

- M1 is a probabilistic classifier, which outputs soft labels (probabilities of a sample belonging to each class) for a binary classification problem, realized by a `sklearn.svm.SVC(probability=True)`.
- M2 is a generative model, which generates samples that belong to the desired class. The input to this model is the soft class label and some other properties.
- D1 has samples, their properties and their binary labels (either 0 or 1) which serve as ground truth to train M1.
- D2 has unlabeled samples and their properties. Therefore, the trained M1 model is used to label them and only then they are used to train M2.

My problem:

> I want to use D1 as input to my generative model M2. However I am
>   unsure whether I should use the ground truth "hard" labels (integers 0
>   or 1) along with the other properties as inputs to M2, **or** firstly use
>   M1 to back-calculate the real-valued soft labels of D1 and feed them to M1.

I hope the diagram sheds some light on my task.

[image]

Comment: Is D1 ever going to change?  i.e. can we understand D1 as a fixed way of "tagging" D2?

Comment: D1 will never change and you are correct, it is somehow a fixed way of tagging D2